# Duplicate content issue (example.com/home AND example.com point to same page)

Tags: php, seo

I am using a post as my home page (WordPress site) by making it a sticky post. I prefer to do it this way versus assigning a page as sticky since posts have more options than pages.

The problem I have that I am looking for a solution to, is that the post is indexed as both `example.com` and `example.com/post-name`.

Both these pages point to the same content and I would like to ask for suggestions on a PHP script that does a "search engine friendly" redirect on requests for `example.com/post-name` so that the post does not get indexed as duplicate content.

PS: a 301 redirect is likely the best solution but I am looking for a solution I can implement in script as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with php or with htaccess.  For PHP solution, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php and http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php - I think you want to check $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']